# Why does Openlayers 6 cause wrong scales?

Tags: openlayers, scale

We've coded an openlayers-based geoportal and recognized a problem with our scale settings.

The displayed scale in our geoportal seems to be wrong. When we connect a wms in our geoportal with an max scale denom of 1:5000, we can display this wms until 1:6500.

In QGIS the WMS is dispayed correctly until 1:5000 and then disappears.

We've already checked the QGIS source code for the calculation of the displayed scale and adapt this in our geoportal.

We use Openlayers 6.1.1 with utm32-projection.

Does somebody had similar problems or any advices about that?

**[Edit]**

For the map we use custom resolutions based on human readable scales converted with the following function:

```
scaleToResolution = function( 
    scale,
    map_units,
    dpi
) {

    scale = scale || 0;
    map_units = map_units || 1;
    dpi = dpi || 1;

    var inch_per_meter = 1/0.0254;

    return scale / map_units / inch_per_meter / dpi;

};
```

The dpi depends on the device.

**[Edit 2]**

The problem was the `TileGrid` with the default `Resolutions` and `Origin` of the `TileWms`-Source. (See [Answer from Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66333175/15260256))

In our geoportal we have a editable select for the scale with predefined scales (e.g. 1:5000, 1:10000 ...).
Additionally the user can enter own scales for a custom view of the map. (e.g. 1:5321).
This works fine with Openlayers ImageWms, XYZ and WMTS.

For the TileWms Openlayers pick the nearest (predefined) resolution of the TileWms when entering a custom scale. (which is logical)

e.g.

```
predefined scale    custom scale

...
1:20000

1:10000

                    1:8345  -->  1:10000 (openlayers choice)
                    1:5321  -->  1:5000 (openlayers choice)

1:5000

1:2500
...
```

When i switch from TileWMS to ImageWMs (Single Tile), Openlayers requests the custom scale.
I want OpenLayers to request the custom scale for the TileWms (like QGIS does).

Is that possible? (e.g. set the resolution of the TileGrid every time the user enter or pick a scale?)

Comment: How are you displaying it in OpenLayers?  For example TileWMS would use fixed resolutions for tilegrid zoom levels, which might not correspond to view resolution.

Comment: @Mike For the map we use custom resolutions based on human readable scales.

For the WMS we use an OpenLayers Tile-Layer with a TileWMS-Source. 
The TileWMS-Source uses the default TileGrid with no extra specified resolutions or origin.

I've updated the question.

Comment: @Mike Thank you for your answer. This give my the right hint and i can confirm the behaviour of OpenLayers when request the tiles after we add the resolutions of the map and an origin to the tilegrid of the TileWms-Source. I've updated the question a second time. Can you please take a look at this?

Comment: OpenLayers creates a cache of loaded tiles, so changing an existing tilegrid or its resolutions dynamically will not work.  You would need to construct a replacement TileMWS source with the updated tilegrid options, then use `layer.setSource()` to update the layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a default tile grid you will have zoom levels with somewhat arbitrary resolutions based initially on the projection extent and a zoom
factor of 2 .  The tiles displayed will come from the zoom level nearest to the view resolution, so depending on the position of the server scale `limit` relative to the tile resolutions the actual display cut-off for visible data might occur anywhere between `limit*sqrt2` and `limit/sqrt2`.
[image]

Defining an explicit tile grid with known resolutions which relate to the server limit, used in conjunction with OpenLayers `maxResolution` or `minResolution` options for the layer, would give more precise control of the cut-off point.